# "export 'ViewPropTypes' (imported as 'RNViewPropTypes') was not found in 'react-native-web/dist/index'

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web, expo-web

I Was Getting This error -

https://forums.expo.dev/t/expo-start-web-failed-to-compile-after-import-native-base/40826

I Solved This By their Solution But Now I am getting another error.
this one

```
Web Bundling complete 1832ms
./app/custom/FilterAutoComplete.js:16:22
"export 'ViewPropTypes' (imported as 'RNViewPropTypes') was not found in 'react-native-web/dist/index'
  14 | } from "react-native-responsive-screen";
  15 | 
> 16 | const ViewPropTypes = RNViewPropTypes || View.propTypes;
     |                      ^
  17 | // const ViewPropTypes = View.propTypes;
  18 | 
  19 | class FilterAutoComplete extends Component {
./node_modules/react-native-check-box/index.js:21:22
"export 'ViewPropTypes' (imported as 'RNViewPropTypes') was not found in 'react-native-web/dist/index'
  19 | import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
  20 | 
> 21 | const ViewPropTypes = RNViewPropTypes || View.propTypes;
     |                      ^
  22 | //const ViewPropTypes = View.propTypes;
  23 | 
  24 | export default class CheckBox extends Component {
```

Please help thanks.

Comment: have you solved it?